# In WoW, is it better to powerlevel a character in group or out of group?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a Level 80 Warrior, and my buddy has a Level 60 Druid. I am interested in speed leveling him for Cataclysm.

For gaining Experience, is it better to stay in the group and just try and zip through Quests as fast as possible? Or is it better to stay outside the group and let him tag monsters and me finish them off?

Being in a group would result in faster killing, but not being in a group would give him full Experience for each kill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest not being grouped.  Then have the lower level player 'tag' the mob e.g. by putting an instant cast on them or a DOT.  Once that starts doing damage, the nameplate of the mob will turn grey for the higher level player.  At this point the lower level will be the one who'll be credited with the XP for the kill,  Now have the higher level AoE them down.  That way there should be no XP penalty and fast kills.

I'm sure I remember people using this approach to get the fastest time to the level cap, by tagging things and having an army of friends / guild members burning them down.  Link to a discussion of this: http://dwarfpriest.com/2008/04/30/mythbusting-1-70-in-a-day/

> On March 19th, the German player Tosog
>   broke all of Athene’s supposed
>   records. He reached 70 in 1 day 4
>   hours and 20 minutes (video here of
>   him hitting 70).
>
> He admitted to being boosted by other
>   players to reach 70 so quickly (he had
>   higher level players (not grouped with
>   him) kill off mobs he tagged). This
>   was a respectable coordinated effort
>   between multiple players.

It was considered a borderline exploit in the 'fastest to the cap' race I think.

Comment: The problem with this is that the low level character needs to do most of the damage, otherwise they're unable to loot the mob. There's similar mechanics at work concerning warlock and hunter pets -- if the pets "solo" a mob on their own, the mob is entirely unlootable by the player.

Comment: But the pet is in a group with the player.  I'm suggesting they shouldn't be grouped.  In that case it's like someone random in the zone 'tagging' a mob as you're starting casting and getting the credit for the kill as a result.  Unless the mechanic on this has been changed recently for how kills are assigned.

Comment: Had a bit of a read - I think the pet thing is a bug of sorts, if the pet is aggressive, then the player hasn't tagged the mob, so no credit for the kill.  In the case above, the 60 should ensure they tag the mob (nameplate changes to grey for the level 80). Then the 60 should get the kill credit.  Will go try this out now to be sure it works

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's been changed recently (been almost a year since I played) they only get full exp out of group if the mobs are green or higher to you.  If they're grey to you, even if your friend tags it, they won't get full exp.  I'm not sure if it's more, less, or the same exp as he would get in group though.

Whether in or out of group though, questing should still be faster, and once you get to mobs that are green to you, your friend can quest while you help out of group to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how geared your warrior is, if you can solo ramps first boss in a single pull, the next mobs minus the last static four in the next and the two bosses. Then you should do that for your druid, that is the fastest for the first couple of levels.

Then move to mana-tombs or crypts, then UK. You should be able to leeroy pull the first area in UK (all the pathing guys) in one pull pretty much. Then move to VH.

If your warrior sucks, you should get a leveling module for TourGuide and grind out outlands / northrend "key" quests quick.

http://www.wowpedia.org/Instances_by_level