# Power leveling using a high level character in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a 80 level elemental shaman and recently my friend joined WoW. I would like to help him level up, is this possible? Can i for example take him to a dungeon (low level dung) and level him up faster than leaving him doing quests etc? I am aiming to get him up to about level 30 or so, allowing him to overcome the boring start faster. What is the best way to do this, is it even possible?

Comment: Isn't the start going to be more fun with Cataclysm? Plus he could start as one of the new classes, which would definitely make it make fun ;-)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12077/in-wow-is-it-better-to-powerlevel-a-character-in-group-or-out-of-group

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest letting him play at his own pace (unless he's an experienced MMORPG player starting WoW for a specific end-game purpose such as raiding / PVP).  In particular if he's new to the genre, that first time exploring the world is such an amazing time, it would be a shame to be boosted through it.

Following the 'Shattering' the starter zones have had an overhaul and are fun to play through and also give a better step by step introduction to game mechanics and how to play your class.

Also the levelling speed now is pretty crazy - people in my guild are making jokes about being level 30 by lunchtime!  It's not quite that fast, but if he gets into it he'll be 30 before he knows it.

Comment: +1, the revamped starter experience has made 1-60 the *least* boring part of the WoW experience. Let him hit 60 at his own pace, and then, if he wants to get to endgame faster, power him through Outland with some Ramps/BF/Underbog/Mana Tombs runs.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about the Cataclysm changes. It will probably be better to let him quest on his own. He has a lot of MMO experience, but not in WoW (played Lineage 2 a lot).

Comment: My biggest problem is that I'm having trouble **not** leveling out of zones before I finish questing them.

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, your totem shouldn't impact his xp for mobs if you are out of the group. So if he tags them and they magma down, he should get full credit.

If you want to help someone at level 30, the best think you can do is usually get a level 30 of your own and quest together.

Comment: +1 - Questing together at the same level is not only more fun, but better all around.  He learns his toon, you learn yours... much better than grabbing a sandwich and watching while your buddy wipes the floor with 20 elite mobs for 2 hours...