# Good class and profession combinations for leveling with a friend in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

this is kind of a follow up to my recent question regarding WoW and leveling ([here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/power-leveling-using-a-high-level-character-in-wow)). My friend decided to try WoW and i would like to play with him from level 1 to 85 with a brand new character. I would like to know what are some good choices of class **and** professions in a 2-man party, so that there is perfect synergy between us? We are on a PvE server and are mainly focused on PvE, so you can disregard anything thats related to PvP (Arenas etc.).

One thing to consider is that my friend strongly favors playing as a hunter (he looked through the classes available in WoW and immediatelly fell in love with this one). However I can probably persuade him to play something else.

As a side note, i was thinking of a Druid+Hunter combo, where Hunter would go for Skin/LW and Druid for Herb/Alch. Both can benefit from Alch (elixirs etc.) and both wear leather (+mail for the hunter). Any other ideas, suggestions?

Comment: Depending on the druid's spec, you may be competing for leather gear until level 40 since feral kitty and hunter both use Agility as their primary stat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of classes, trying to cover all three roles between the two of you is a good target. When you guys are questing together by yourselves, having one person be DPS and the other healing helps keeps downtime to a minimum. And if you guys decide to use the Dungeon Finder, having one person able to heal and the other be able to tank ensures you'll never have to wait long in the queue.

Blizzard has homogenized the classes over the years so there is a tremendous amount of overlap between the classes and specs. As long as you guys cover the three class roles, feel free to choose whatever fancies you.

For reference the hybrid classes are:

- All three roles: Paladins, Druids
- DPS + Healing: Priests, Shamen
- DPS + Tanking: Warriors, Death Knights

If you're going to take my advice about role coverage, you'll want to avoid Mages, Hunters, Warlocks, and Rogues as they can only be one role: DPS.

Since you're talking 1-85 play, Death Knights are off the table as they start at level 55.

Putting it all together:

- Person 1: Paladin, Druid, or Warrior (to cover tanking)
- Person 2: Paladin, Druid, Priest, or Shaman (to cover healing)

In terms of professions, I'd avoid the heavy crafting professions that take a lot of time to level up and are usually taken for the Bind-on-pickup endgame recipes: Blacksmithing, Tailoring, Engineering, Leatherworking. Instead, focus on the professions that'll let you help each other out while leveling, like Enchanting and Alchemy, or the gathering professions, like Mining and Skinning, which will prove lucrative and won't require too much (if any) time soloing.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Mark. Can you tell me what to choose if my friends goes for the hunter? Do you think druid will be a good choice because he can be either a healer or a tank?

Comment: Either paladin or druid would be a fine choice. I'd probably choose paladin personally, as the hunter is going to be mostly unable to protect the healer and a paladin healer can take a beating due to mail (and eventually, plate) armor. Just know that if one person chooses a pure DPS class, it puts a lot of pressure on the other person to fulfill the other two roles.

Comment: Thanks, i will go for the druid, i don't like the bubble boy ;)

Comment: +1. I've been leveling up a Warrior with a friend playing a Druid. Having all 3 roles covered means we can fit into any group, or switch roles when one gets boring.

Comment: Same here - my troll druid is leveling with a tauren paladin.  She does tank/melee DPS and I do heals/ranged DPS.  When we're questing, we both keep an eye on each other's health bars and heal up as appropriate.  As far as professions go, she took herb/alchemy and I'm doing mining/engineering.  So we never compete with each other for raw resources, either.

Comment: It is not necessary restrictive, except heal+tank for instance quene purposes. I played grp leveling as mage + shaman(dpd). So far as shaman can hold priest from melee. It can still overkill and less down time. The main principle is to cover the weakness of partner. Who does know warlock + mage still can work out fine;)

Comment: Firts time i tried it, I goes for a shadow priest... Since it was before the specializations update, soloing from 1 to 85 was pretty hard, but thanks to that i gained some good skills for "last hope" dugeon healing, and gained som good reflexes. Then i begun a new player, with my friends who had invited me, and we made a shaman/paladin duo. It take us less than 2 days to go from lvl 1 to 60, then about 15/16 days for lvl 80 (yup, pre-cataclysm). If you have at least a heal in your group, you'll have an easy way. If the second one can assume tank, or heal too, it's even easier...

Comment: A Hunter can fulfill the tanking role easily (for leveling) in a 2-man party with a properly specced Tenacity pet.  Your buddy can still be a hunter!

Comment: It will still be a little harder than him playing a tank class...

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to go the complete other direction and say for strict 1-85, a pair of DPS will serve best.  Leveling is about killing things fast.  Normal mobs will barely scratch a even a cloth wearer.  The synergy comes from sharing kill quest credit by each person taking on their own mobs.  2 people focusing on 1 monster is just wasting time.  Every class has some form of self healing, and otherwise bandaids & food can get you through if you really need healing.  You might want to consider a hunter or warlock as one of the dps since a pet can be handy, but really any 2 solid DPS classes will tear through levels.  Going into a tanking or healing spec is just going to slow things down.

Aside from first aid, professions tend to hinder leveling.  It is ridiculously easy to max a gathering profession at level 85, and subsequently is easy to work with a crafting profession as well.

This is just strictly advice to get you from 1-85.  If you want to consider after that if you want groups, then one of you should pick a hybrid that can play a tank.  A tank in the group = instant queue pops.

Answer (score 1):

I have been running this same scenario in my head and I think the following sounds good:

Mage /lock- there can be nothing bad about aie grinding up to 12 mobs at a time.

Shad priest/lock-  free heals, free manage, 0 downtime and a pet. Seems a good synergy

Paladin/mage- same principle as the lock-mage, but now you have better versatility

Answer (score 1):

My friend and I do a hunter/hunter combo and we just destroy everything.  The only bad thing with a hunter/hunter combo is no one can really heal.

My second choice would be a hunter/rogue combo where the hunter just gets all the aggro on them and then the rogue sneaks up behind and does some sneaky kill work. My third choice would be a mage and lock because together they are really good for arena play. Again the bad thing is the lack of a healer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise taking 2 hybrids, such as druid/paladin, druid/shaman, druid/warrior or any other such combination whereby at least 1 can tank, and 1 can heal.

The justification for this, is if you're essentially spending most of your playtime together, then if one of you tanks and the other heals, you'll be able to find groups a LOT faster than if you were both playing pure DPS roles.

This can help a lot if you intend to gain levels faster and a little bit less stressful